# Prove the solution set is a subgroup under mod 2 addition

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, normal-subgroups

Given the following system:

$x_1 + x_2 \ \qquad \qquad+ x_5 = 0$

$x_1 \ \qquad + x_3 \qquad +x_5 = 0$

$x_1 \ \qquad +x_3 + x_4 \qquad = 0$

$\ \qquad x_2 + x_3 + x_4 \qquad = 0$

The augmented matrix of the system is

$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
  1&1&0&0&1&0\\
  1&0&1&0&1&0\\
  1&0&1&1&0&0\\
  0&1&1&1&0&0
\end{array}
\right] $

Row reduction in mod 2 gives the following matrix.

$ \left[
\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
  1&1&0&0&1&0\\
  1&0&1&0&1&0\\
  1&0&1&1&0&0\\
  0&1&1&1&0&0
\end{array}
\right] $

so the general solution is $x_1 = x_3 ,x_2 = x_3, x_3 = x_3, x_4 = 0, x_5 = 0$ since the only free variable is $x_3$ which implies there are $2^1 = 2 $ solutions, which would be either when $x_3 = 1$ or $0$ since the operation is mod 2 addition.

So that means the solution set is $(0,0,0,0,0)$ and $(1,1,1,0,0)$. I want to prove the solution set is a subgroup of $\Bbb Z_2^5$ under coordinatewise mod 2 addition.

So far, I let $A = (0,0,0,0,0) , B = (1,1,1,0,0)$, and I want to show $H = \{A,B\} \subset \Bbb Z_2^5$

I know for a subgroup you must prove the operation is associative and closed, identity exists, inverse exists. This is what I have so far..

I know the operation is closed and associative because:

$A +_2 A = (0,0,0,0,0) = A$

$A +_2 B = (1,1,1,0,0) = B$

$B +_2 A = (1,1,1,0,0) = B$

$B +_2 B = (0,0,0,0,0) = A$

I'm having some trouble with the identity/inverse.

$A \in H$ then $e = A +_2 A^{-1} = (0,0,0,0,0) +_2 (1,1,1,1,1) = (1,1,1,1,1)$, So $e \in H$, but that implies $e = (1,1,1,1,1)$, which causes a problem with inverse:

$B \in H$ then $B^{-1} = e +_2 B^{-1} = (1,1,1,1,1) +_2 (0,0,0,1,1) = (1,1,1,0,0)$ which is equal to $B$ and not $B^{-1}$.

My intuition initially told me that the identity element should be $(0,0,0,0,0)$, but that isn't what I got with the math... if it were $(0,0,0,0,0)$ then the inverse would work as well and there would be no problem.

Comment: Why would $(1,1,1,1,1)$ be the inverse of $(0,0,0,0,0)$?

Comment: @GTonyJacobs I assumed because they were opposites... I guess there is my mistake? What should it be then? Still $(0,0,0,0,0)$?

Comment: The identity element in any additive group is the zero element, and it is always its own inverse. Moreover, when you're talking about addition modulo $2$, every element is its own inverse. Do you see why?

Comment: Ah yes. Since $ 1 + 1 = 0$ and $ 0 + 0 = 0$. Thanks

Comment: I think this problem is actually much easier. Since the system is homogeneous, the solution set is a subspace. Considered as a system in $\Bbb Z_2^5$, any subspace is a subgroup.... and we're done? I'd post that as an answer, but I'm not convinced there isn't something I'm missing.....